# Performance of image processing algorithms over android smartphones

Tags: android, performance, image-processing

I am looking forward to start a project that will use OCR , Object tracking and other Image processing algorithms on Android and I want to accelerate these algorithms using external hardware accelerators on FPGA using the Open Accessory API.

Do Image processing apps perform bad and needs custom hardware for acceleration ? Is there a resource to know about performance of image processing algorithms on smart phones and embedded systems without writing one ?

Comment: We have done extensive image processing work on Neon using Android and we have been happy. You can get pretty good results. External FPGA stuff may be slow due to bus bandwidth issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only viable to do optimization after you have done measurements for your particular case.

If you need HW acceleration you might want to check out [renderscript](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html). It gives you access to GPU hardware to perform generic computations.

Comment: hmmmm, sounds right .
But I want to start a project that involves software and hardware on fpga so I want some indications or previous projects to see if the idea is really practical or the algorithms are doing fine using software only .

Answer (score 1):

[JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) offers a number of image processing algorithms. It is basically a Java wrapper for OpenCV. I found this post regarding OpenCV and OCR: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284214/simple-ocr-programming-tutorials-articles. Performance really depends on the size of the image and processor on the device. Not sure about using a FPGA.  Have you considered using the "cloud" to offload processing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenCV for image processing in Android. The best tutorial I can find is [OpenCV setup on Eclipse](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html). However if you do image processing in Java the results will be slow, so use second part of the tutorial to program in C then using JNI make the code run for android.
But still a lot of image re sizing and defining region of interest is needed to make the program run in real time if you do object recognition.